# Cannot get chosen select value after first iteration

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-chosen

I cannot get the multiselect select (chosen) value after the first iteration of the loop. Following is the code.

```
<div class='group'>  
   <div class='questions'>
       <div class='question'>
           <select class='countries'></select>      
       </div>
       <div class='question dependant' data-country='US'></div>
       <div class='question dependant' data-country='UK'></div>
       <div class='question dependant' data-country='US'></div>
       <div class='question dependant' data-country='US'></div>
   </div>
</div>    
$('.group .questions .question.dependant').each(function(){
    let _value = '';
    _value = $('select.countries').val();
    // its the same as below. both the lines give the same result.
    // _value = $('select.countries').chosen().val();
    if(_value == $(this).data('country')) $(this).addClass('hidden');
    console.log(_value);
)};
```

I get the value on first iteration.
How to get the value on all iterations?

NOTE: PAGE HAS ONLY ONE COUNTRIES SELECT ELEMENT.

Comment: I would imagine from the context you have multiple `.countries select` elements, and getting the `val()` from a collection will only return the first one. You need to find the `select` related to the current `.question.dependant` in the loop. How you do that will depend on your HTML structure. As you've not shown that we can't really answer your question.

Comment: You don't need `chosen`, you can use `val` directly

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i have only one countries select.

Comment: @AhmadAlfy i also tried with that. but no result.

Comment: In that case the issue is not clear. If you're selecting the same element in every iteration, the value is going to be the same.

Comment: dear friend can you please paste your HTML code also. ass @AhmadAlfy mentioned you don't need the `chosen` method and probably you don't need the `each()` loop.

Comment: If you have only one `select` element in your document why not set an ID to the element to be easily identified with `$('#yourID').val();` ?

Comment: @MolhamAlNasr i have provided the detailed code.